# What should I do to use bing translator in iOS?

Tags: translation, bing-api

I want to translate a word in my app. First I wanted to use Google Translate but I saw Google Translate's API is not free. So I tried to use Bing Translator, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis), but in step 3 I can't find "*Get started by applying for an AppId now*". So how can I create an appID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Bing Translate API has been renamed as Microsoft Translator.

That page reads:

> Developers with existing AppIDs can continue using Bing Search API 2.0
>   until August 1, 2012. On and after this date, Bing Search API 2.0
>   AppIDs will no longer return results. Developers can continue using
>   the API by signing up for it in the Windows Azure Marketplace. Read
>   the Migration Guide and FAQs to get started.

So it looks like you have to sign up for the Windows Azure Marketplace if you want to continue using the Bing APIs.

You can find the Microsoft Translator on the Azure marketplace at [this](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/1899a118-d202-492c-aa16-ba21c33c06cb) link. By the looks of it, it doesn't look like its free either. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512419.aspx) link has what looks like the API documentation. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778651/how-to-propertly-use-bing-translate-api) related question on SO.

There is a [project](https://github.com/H2CO3/BingTranslate) on Github which offers a client to the API for iOS.

Comment: How could I install `BingTranslate.framework` in my project and Why when I `import "BingTranslate.h"` in my appdelegate It has error is not found `BTClient.h`

Answer (score 1):

The above information is mostly correct except for it not being free part. There is a free tier of service still available via Bing/Microsoft translator. When you go through the subscription process, simply choose the free tier.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the sample app on github doesnt support the new authentication Azure marketplace token that bing translator is now using. I downloaded it and it doesnt work, just returns "invalid appid" error all the time. You cant even get app ID anymore from microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few translation API's available for free. Google translate API's is also not free, but google translate API is the cheapest and easy to use. It charges $20 for 1M characters and supports many languages. You can look at more information here,

https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started.

Thanks.